# yeelight YDLT001: Cannot connect Yeelight Monitor Bar to my computer - Wifi is refusing the connection

Tags: wireless-networking, iot

I recently bought a Yeelight YDLT001, a nice looking extension to my computer that (a) enables the computer to control some ambient light behind the monitor, and (b) a lamp that lits up the keyboard. It goes on your monitor and has front and back-light. It can be controlled from the PC using Razer Chroma and Overwolf. The German web page https://www.nerdsheaven.de/yeelight-yltd001-yltd003-ab-screenlight-und-rgb-stimmungslicht/ gives more details.

This question is about enabling the connection between the device and the computer (--> topic of this forum ;-)

It is a smart device and need to be connected to your Wifi. After that, the computer can interface to the device and control the settings. The procedure is quite simple. Turn it on and off 5 times by disconnecting the USB-C cable. Then a WIFI network called somthing like Yeeligh-.... appears. Then the device can be configured to connect to that network.  I had to replace the USB charger as it only has American sockets (I am in Germany). The Yeelight lights up. The backlight is always on, the front light switches on and off.

Problem: The Yeelight WIFI appears. I am trying to connect from the iphone, the icon spins for a while, the it says "Cannot Connect". Soon after the Yeelight Wifi disappears.

I tried:

- PC WIFI (and iPhone XS Max, iPad, Android)  - always same effect
- gave my Wifi 2.4 GhZ a different name (the Yeelight only likes 2.4 GHz)
- millions way of resetting the device (disconnect USB-C, disconnect the power socket, disconnect the bar from the bracket, ...)
- different USB charger - interesting enough on the more powerful charger (e.g. for Laptops) the device does not work. I had it finally on a charger delivering 5V/3A. Some reports in other fora said it needs 5V/2A/10W  (hopefully "or more" ;-)

Bottom line... it seems there is a bug that prevents to connect to the Wifi. Any help appreciated...

Comment: All those extra words, but you still end by saying you're trying to connect this light to your phone, which remains off topic here.

Comment: Sorry, this is not about connecting a light to a phone. Please read the message again. Mobile phones are only mentioned as an additional test for the WIfi. The complete procedure is about PCs/Laptop, the liught is for illustrating the key board of the PC, the ambient light is for making the monitor more user friendly. The control is dojne with the PC software Razer Chroma or via iopbroker from the PC.

SO
- this is about a peripherie device of a PC
- it is about the connectivty issue (explicitly mentioned as an allowed post)
- the process is about the PC controlling the ambient light

Comment: "Problem: The Yeelight WIFI appears. I am trying to connect from the iphone, the icon spins for a while, the it says "Cannot Connect". Soon after the Yeelight Wifi disappears." can you clarify what happens with the *pc* and then have the behaviour with an iphone as additional information?

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturers support? You may have a faulty device?

Comment: Very likely broken. It happens, and it can manifest in the strangest ways.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I contacted the manufacturer who say I should configure the software to use the Chinese main server. But as said, the device is not even connecting to the Wifi. So yes, I assume it is broken. Thanks for confirmation.